# Modbus TCP server with Python

Tags: python, server, tcp, modbus

I am starting a program using Python. I wanna send some informations of Python to Simply Modbus TCP Client. To be honest I really don't know to use Python, at the same time i`m learning Modbus.

The error messages I am getting is:

```
runfile('C:/Users/rafa_/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/TCC_v.0/2/simhvac.py', wdir='C:/Users/rafa_/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/TCC_v.0/2')
Erro:  ("'Hvac' object has no attribute '_server'",)
```

My code is over there (somebody can help me):

```py
from threading import Thread
from pyModbusTCP.server import DataBank, ModbusServer
from time import sleep
import time

class ServidorMODBUS():
    
    """ Classe Servidor Modbus"""
    
    def __init__(self, host_ip, port):
        
        """construtor"""
        
        self._server = ModbusServer(host=host_ip, port=port, no_block=True)
        self._db = DataBank
        
class Hvac(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.Ts = 0.5           # Sampling period in seconds

        # Initial conditions
        self.temperature = 25 # Initial temperature (Celsius degree)
        self.co2 = 400        # Initial CO2 concentration (ppm)
        self.humity = 33      # Initial Humidity (% RH) 

        self.number_of_occup = 1
        self.co2_air_inlet = 200
        self.T_air = 23

        self.T_ac = 20
        self.H_ac = 90
        self.H_air = 90


        # CO2 Parameters
        self.co2_params = {
            'a1': -0.8964, 
            'kn': 2.108,
            'ki': 0.0579, 
            'kd': self.Ts
        } 

        # Temperature Parameters
        self.temperature_params = {
            'beta_i1'  : -1.179,
            'beta_i2'  : 0.2567, 
            'alfa_ac'  : 0.0043,
            'alfa_air' : 0.0762,
            'alfa_0'   : 0.0013,
            'alfa_1'   : -9.96E-4,
            'alfa_I'   : -3.06E-4
        }

        # Humity Parameters
        self.humity_params = {
            'delta_i1'  : -1.6696,
            'delta_i2'  : 0.6844,
            'gamma_ac'  : -2.83E-4,
            'gamma_air' : 0.0147,
            'gamma_T'   : 2.16E-4,
            'gamma_0'   : 0.0016,
            'gamma_1'   : 0.0018,
            'gamma_I'   : 4.98E-5
        }


    def run(self):

        co2 = [self.co2, self.co2]
        temp = [self.temperature, self.temperature]
        humity = [self.humity, self.humity]

        co2_il = [self.co2_air_inlet, self.co2_air_inlet]

        """Execuçao MODBUS"""
        
        try:
            self._server.start()
            print("Servidor MODBUS online")
            while True:
              
                t = time.time()
                # Process CO2, temperature, humity
                (a1, kn, ki, kd) = self.co2_params.values()
                n = self.number_of_occup
                i = self.co2_air_inlet
                d = 0 # disturbance
                self.co2 = kn*n + ki*i + kd*d - a1*co2[0]
    
                (beta_i1, beta_i2, alfa_ac, alfa_air, alfa_0, alfa_1, alfa_I) = self.temperature_params.values()
                T_ac = self.T_ac
                T_air = self.T_air
                self.temperature = alfa_ac*T_ac+alfa_air*T_air+alfa_0*co2[0]+alfa_1*co2[1]+alfa_I*co2_il[1] - beta_i1*temp[0]-beta_i2*temp[1]
    
    
                (delta_i1,delta_i2,gamma_ac,gamma_air,gamma_T,gamma_0,gamma_1,gamma_I) = self.humity_params.values()
                H_ac = self.H_ac
                H_air = self.H_air
                self.humity = gamma_ac*H_ac+gamma_air*H_air+gamma_T*self.temperature+gamma_0*co2[0]+gamma_1*co2[1]+gamma_I*co2_il[1]-delta_i1*humity[0]-delta_i2*humity[1]
                
                # Update delays
                co2 = [self.co2, co2[0]]
                temp = [self.temperature, temp[0]]
                humity = [self.humity, humity[0]]
                co2_il = [self.co2_air_inlet, co2_il[0]]
                
                print('CO2:', self.co2, 'Temp:', self.temperature, 'Humidity:', self.humity)
                time.sleep(self.Ts-(time.time()-t))
                
                self._db.set_words(1000, co2, temp, humity, co2_il)
                print("________________")
                print("Tabela MODBUS")
                print(f'Holding Register \r\n R1000: {self.db.get_words(1000)}\r\n R2000 {self.db.get_words(2000)}')
                print(f'Coil \r\n R1000:{self.db.get_bits(1000)}')
                sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Erro: ", e.args)
```

The below screenshots show the error.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Please let us know the specific issue you are facing (an error, unexpected result, cannot work out how do do a specific task etc) - see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance.

Comment: Actually the program run but don’t send the package to client

Comment: So when you query the server you are getting an error? Please show how you are querying it and what the result is (edit the question and add extra info).

Comment: I am going to home now and I gonna share some print screen, in a nutshell, the programs is cooling but is not sending the information to client

Answer (score 0):

When posting a question on Stack overflow its good to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because this makes it easier to for others to quickly assess your issue (and in many cases you will solve the issue yourself when creating the example). The code you pasted (including that in the screenshots) can be reduced to (try [here](https://code.labstack.com/xbKwVAf6)):

```
from threading import Thread

class Hvac(Thread):

    def run(self):
        try:
            self._server.start()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Erro: ", e.args)

HvacSim = Hvac()
HvacSim.start()
```

running this gives the same error you are receiving:

```
Erro:  ("'Hvac' object has no attribute '_server'",)
```

You can actually simplify this further by removing the `try`/`catch` which will result in a different (and more helpful) error message (telling you the line the error occurred etc).

Its likely you are thinking "but I defined `_server` here":

```
class ServidorMODBUS():
    
    """ Classe Servidor Modbus"""    
    def __init__(self, host_ip, port):        
        """construtor"""        
        self._server = ModbusServer(host=host_ip, port=port, no_block=True)
```

However that is within the class `ServidorMODBUS` and not `Hvac` (you don't actually appear to be using `ServidorMODBUS` at all). It's not really clear what you intend to do with `ServidorMODBUS` (I would guess you want to create an instance of this in the the `__init__` for `Hvac`).